# Developing task to synchronize managed dependencies with another directory in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to write a task which retrieves the dependency jars and puts them in a single directory at the project root.  Here's what I have so far:

```
retrieveManaged := true

val libDir = settingKey[File]("the directory to retrieve dependency libraries to")

lazy val getLibs = taskKey[Unit]("retrieves all dependency libraries to the libDir")

libDir := baseDirectory.value / "libs"

getLibs := {
  val a = update.value
  sbt.IO.delete(libDir.value)
  for (src <- (managedDirectory.value ** "*.jar").get) {
    sbt.IO.copyFile(src, libDir.value / src.getName, true)
  }
}
```

I use `retrieveManaged := true` so that sbt will copy the dependencies to `managedDirectory`.  I then copy those libraries to a directory which I have defined.  My questions are:

1. I want my task to depend on the `update` task, to ensure that the dependencies have been copied to `managedDirectory` first.  If I understand  [How can I call another task from my SBT task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110673/how-can-i-call-another-task-from-my-sbt-task), I should be able to do this by calling `update.value`.  But this doesn't seem to work.
2. Instead of copying the files, I'd really like to "synchronize".  This means that only newly added files should be copied, and any files which no longer exist should be removed.  How can I do this?

### Update

Thanks to Jacek's suggestion, I was able to come up with the following solution, which addresses #1.  I still need to figure out how to do #2 (synchronize instead of copy).

```
getLibs := {
  sbt.IO.delete(libDir.value)
  val depFiles = update.value.matching((s: String) => Set("compile", "runtime") contains s)
  for (depFile <- depFiles) {
    sbt.IO.copyFile(depFile, libDir.value / depFile.getName, true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to **really** use the value of `update` task and parse its result. That would sort out the issue 1 and 2. If it does not, attach the symptoms to your question.

All `val a = update.value` does it to execute `update` task and assign its value to `a`. Since you don't use `a` at all, you lose all the previous information `update` gives you. To see what it is execute `show update` in the shell.

```
[triggeredby]> help update
Resolves and optionally retrieves dependencies, producing a report.

[triggeredby]> show update
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/triggeredby/}triggeredby...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Update report:
[info]  Resolve time: 2152 ms, Download time: 114 ms, Download size: 0 bytes
[info]  compile:
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3 (): (Artifact(scala-library,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar)
[info]  runtime:
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3 (): (Artifact(scala-library,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar)
[info]  test:
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3 (): (Artifact(scala-library,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar)
[info]  provided:
[info]  optional:
[info]  compile-internal:
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3 (): (Artifact(scala-library,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar)
[info]  runtime-internal:
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3 (): (Artifact(scala-library,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar)
[info]  test-internal:
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3 (): (Artifact(scala-library,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar)
[info]  plugin:
[info]  sources:
[info]  docs:
[info]  pom:
[info]  scala-tool:
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.3: (Artifact(scala-compiler,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-compiler.jar)
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3 (): (Artifact(scala-library,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar)
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.3 (): (Artifact(scala-reflect,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-reflect.jar)
[info]      org.scala-lang:jline:2.10.3: (Artifact(jline,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/jline.jar)
[info]      org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.4: (Artifact(jansi,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/jars/jansi-1.4.jar)
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Mar 14, 2014 12:16:26 AM
```

I think it's pretty much what you need - use the return value to fit your needs.

Comment: Ok so I'm an sbt noob.  I don't really understand what that means.  Regarding #1, all I know is that I want "update" to happen before my task gets executed.  I don't see how your suggestion addresses #2 at all.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.  My understanding of "update" is that it retrieves the declared dependencies and copies them to managedDirectory.  I want "update" to happen before my task happens because I rely on the side effect this produces, not on any value this might return.

Comment: See another update with `help update`. It indeed does the side effect - retrieves declared deps, but it's a side effect, right? What's the output of the task - the report of what it did and I believe that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks Jacek, I had a look at the API, including UpdateReport/RichUpdateReport, and I now understand what I need to do to retrieve the dependencies.  But I still don't know how to "synchronize" (in the sense described in my question).  I'm currently doing a "copy" which is semantically a little different.