# Combine several sbt tasks into one

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm a little confused on the Scala/SBT documentation for creating Scala tasks. Currently I can run the following from the command line:

```
sbt ";set target := file(\"$PWD/package/deb-upstart\"); set serverLoading in Debian := com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.Upstart; debian:packageBin; set target := file(\"$PWD/package/deb-systemv\"); set serverLoading in Debian := com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archtypes.ServerLoader.SystemV; debian:packageBin; set target := file(\"$PWD/package/rpm-systemd\"); rpm:packageBin"
```

This resets my target each time to a different directory (deb-upstart, deb-systemv and rpm-systemd) and runs an sbt-native-package task for each of those settings. (Yes, I realizing I'm compiling it three different times; but sbt-native-packager doesn't seems to have a setting for the artifact directory)

This works fine from a bash prompt, but I've been trying to put the same target into jenkins (replacing $PWD with $WORKSPACE) and I can't seem to get the quote escaping correct. I thought it might be easier just to have a task in either by build.sbt or project/Build.scala that runs all three of those tasks, changing out the target variable each time (and replacing $PWD or $TARGET with the full path of the base directory).

I've attempted the following:

```
 lazy val packageAll = taskKey[Unit]("Creates deb-upstart, deb-systenv and rpm-systemd packages")

packageAll := {
  target := baseDirectory.value / "package" / "deb-upstart"

  serverLoading in Debian := com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.Upstart

  (packageBin in Debian).value

  target := baseDirectory.value / "package" / "deb-systemv"

  serverLoading in Debian := com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.SystemV

  (packageBin in Debian).value

  target := baseDirectory.value / "package" / "rpm-systemd"

  (packageBin in Rpm).value

}
```

But the trouble is the .value causes the tasks to get evaluated before my task is even run, so they don't get the new target setting (as stated in this other question: [How can I call another task from my SBT task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110673/how-can-i-call-another-task-from-my-sbt-task))

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you try to extract each custom `packageBin` step into a custom task and then aggregate them with `packageAll`?

The output directories if only changed once can be set with `target in Rpm` or `target in Debian` as well.

Comment: @Muki I wish I could just to `target in [Setting]` but if you look carefully, you'll see I change the target twice for Debian, once for the Upstart ServerLoader and once for the SystemV ServerLoader. How would I go about extracting each packageBin into a custom task?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured this out for you :)
As you already mentioned, combining a multiple tasks in a single one where some of the tasks depend on the same setting, doesn't work out as expected.

Instead we do the following

1. Create a task for each of our custom steps, e.g. *packaging debian for upstart*
2. Define an alias that executes these commands in order

## Define tasks

```
lazy val packageDebianUpstart = taskKey[File]("creates deb-upstart package")
lazy val packageDebianSystemV = taskKey[File]("creates deb-systenv package")
lazy val packageRpmSystemD = taskKey[File]("creates rpm-systenv package")
```

## Example task implementation

The implementation is pretty simple and the same for each of
the tasks.

```
// don't forget this
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes._

packageDebianUpstart := {
  // define where you want to put your stuff
  val output = baseDirectory.value / "package" / "deb-upstart"

  // run task
  val debianFile = (packageBin in Debian).value

  // place it where  you want
  IO.move(debianFile, output)
  output
}
```

## Define alias

And now compose these tasks into a single alias with

```
addCommandAlias("packageAll", "; clean " + 
                          "; set serverLoading in Debian := com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.SystemV" +
                          "; packageDebianSystemV " +
                          "; clean " + 
                          "; set serverLoading in Debian := com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.Upstart" +
                          "; packageDebianUpstart " + 
                          "; packageRpmSystemD")
```

You can look at the complete code [here](https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples/tree/master/multiple-package-outputs).

### Update

Setting the SystemLoader inside the alias seems to be the right
way to solve this. A clean is unfortunately necessary between
each build for the same output format.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It renames the package to deb-upstart instead of putting it in a directory (I tried adding a `scalax.file.Path(output).createDirectory()` right after the `val output`, but it still renames the packages rather than placing them in their own directory). Furthermore, if you run `dpkg-deb -c deb-systemv`, you'll see it's actually the upstart version. `.value` runs those tasks before your custom task. The only way to do this is with a Command. I've been trying to work on one; may issue a pull request if I can figure it out.

Comment: I updated the example. Setting inside the tasks seems to be handled not correctly by sbt or is done in another way. Setting it from the outside via an alias works.

The directory is created correctly for me and it moves the files as described. `IO.move(package, outputfolder)`.