# how to publish-local from an sbt task (build.scala)

Tags: scala, sbt

How do you publish a project to the local ivy repository, from within code inside `Build.scala`, rather than from the sbt command-line? This should perform the same as issuing the `publish` command on the sbt command-line.

I have a multi-project build definition, and I would like (only) one of the contained projects to get published to the local ivy repository.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20110673/86485?

Comment: Given the piecemeal nature of sbt documentation, it is very hard for mere mortals to compose the answer by just following that more general question, let alone for a `Build.scala`.

Answer (score 4):

In an `.sbt` build, you'd write:

```
val myTask = taskKey[Unit](
  "runs publish and does some other stuff too")
myTask := {
  val result = publishLocal.value
  println("do some other stuff too")
}
```

If you take that stuff and drop it into a `.scala` build, you get:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {
  val myTask = taskKey[Unit](
    "runs publish and does some other stuff too")
  lazy val root = Project(
    id = "foo",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Seq(
      myTask := {
        val result = publishLocal.value
        println("do some other stuff too")
      }))
}
```