# Running sbt task twice with different settings

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I run a task twice, the first time with settings defined in `build.sbt` and a second time  with some other setting? The code is going to be something like this:

```
val childSetting = settingKey[String]("Some setting")

val childTask = taskKey[String]("Child task")

childTask := ???

val parentTask = taskKey[String]("Parent task")

parentTask := {
  val initial = childTask.value
  // Do some stuff
  // Run childTask again with different setting
  // Do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

sbt [deduplicates](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Custom-Settings.html#Deduplication+of+task+dependencies) tasks so, for example, given the following definition of `parentTask`

```
val childSetting = settingKey[String]("Some setting")
childSetting := "Live long and prosper"

val childTask = taskKey[String]("Child task")
childTask := {
  val x = childSetting.value
  println(x)
  x
}

val parentTask = taskKey[String]("Parent task")
parentTask := {
  val initial = childTask.value
  val another = childTask.value
  initial
}
```

it might seem we are executing `childTask` twice in

```
parentTask := {
  val initial = childTask.value
  val another = childTask.value
  initial
}
```

however executing `sbt parentTask` we see the side-effect `println(x)` outputs

```
Live long and prosper
```

only once. So it seems we cannot simply use `value` macro, which is the recommended way of executing tasks. Try using `runTask` like so

```
parentTask := {
  val st = state.value
  val extracted = Project.extract(st)
  val (st2, initial) = extracted.runTask(childTask, st)
  val st3 = extracted.appendWithSession(Seq(childSetting := "nuqneH"), st2)
  val (st4, another) = Project.extract(st3).runTask(childTask, st3)
  another
}
```

Now executing `sbt parentTask` runs `println(x)` side-effect of `childTask` twice, each time with different state

```
Live long and prosper
...
nuqneH
```

However executing tasks directly with `runTask` is not recommended because it [bypasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20123930/5205022) sbt's strengths

> Invoking the task directly would do an end run around the dependency
>   system, the parallel execution system, etc.

and can lead to [race conditions](https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt?at=58d0536e58ad4eb028359b9a)

> Be careful with runTask. It executes outside of sbt's task graph. Can
>   lead to race conditions, etc. See: sbt/sbt#2970

Alternatively try defining a command, although usage of commands is similarly [discouraged](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#Use+settings+and+tasks.+Avoid+commands.), for example, given

```
commands += Command.command("foo") { state =>
  "childTask" :: """set childSetting := "nuqneH"""" :: "childTask" :: state
}
```

executing `sbt foo` outputs

```
Live long and prosper
...
nuqneH
```

where we see `println(x)` side-effect of `childTask` executed twice.